# New-Object : Cannot bind parameter 'Property'. Cannot convert the "" value of type PSCustomObject to type IDictionary

Tags: sql-server, powershell, automation

I'm having a hard time converting results from Invoke-SqlCmd to a PSCustomobject.

So, I input my query and SQL server, then I run the Invoke-SqlCmd function, and then I try to add data from that (the database logical name, and the autogrowth status) to my PSCustomobject, so I can return it back to my modules public function.

```
$sqlinstance = "---"
$query = "---"

    if ($sqlInstance -match "---") {
        $dbAutogrowIGP = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $query -ServerInstance $sqlInstance

        if ($dbAutogrowIGP.Growth -gt 100 -and $dbAutogrowIGP.Growth -lt 500) {
            $autogrowStatus = [PSCustomObject]@{
                'SQL_Instance'  = $dbAutogrowIGP.LogicalName
                'Check'         = "Autogrow"
                'Status'        = "green"
                'Status_reason' = ""
            }
            New-Object -Type Dictionary -Property $autogrowStatus
        }

        foreach ($db in $dbAutogrowIGP) {
            if ($db.Growth -lt 100 -or $db.Growth -gt 500 -and $db.Growth -notlike "%") {
                $autogrowStatus = [PSCustomObject]@{
                    'SQL_Instance'  = $db.LogicalName
                    'Check'         = "Autogrow"
                    'Status'        = "red"
                    'Status_reason' = "$($db.LogicalName) has autogrowth set to $($db.Growth)."
                }
                New-Object -Type Dictionary -Property $autogrowStatus
            }

            if ($db.Growth -like "%") {
                $autogrowStatus = [PSCustomObject]@{
                    'SQL_Instance'  = $db.LogicalName
                    'Check'         = "Autogrow"
                    'Status'        = "yellow"
                    'Status_reason' = "$($db.LogicalName) has autogrowth set percentually, it should be an absolute number."
                }
                New-Object -Type Dictionary -Property $autogrowStatus
            }
        }
    }

return $autogrowStatus
```

I've debugged it, and I've noticed it fails on the New-object call. I've tried both Dictionary and PSObject/PSCustomObject - however neither works

In my other functions, this works as expected, however in those, I'm using dbatools to make a call.

```
        $getLogSizeIGP = Get-DbaDbLogSpace -sqlInstance $sqlInstance

        if ($getLogSizeIGP.LogSize.Gigabyte -lt 10 -and $getLogSizeIGP.LogSpaceUsedPercent -lt 50) {
            $logStatus = @{
                'SQL_Instance'  = $getLogSizeIGP.SqlInstance
                'Check'         = "Log_size"
                'Status'        = [gmEnvStatuses]::green
                'Status_reason' = ""
            }
            New-Object -Type PSObject -Property $logStatus
        }
```

How would I go about solving this issue?

This is the whole error message:

```
New-Object : Cannot bind parameter 'Property'. Cannot convert the "@{SQL_Instance=Maintenance_log; Check=Autogrow; Status=red; Status_reason=Maintenance_log has autogrowth set to 10%.}" value of type "System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject" to type 
"System.Collections.IDictionary".
At C:\Users\---\Desktop\autogrowth.ps1:50 char:55
+                 New-Object -Type Dictionary -Property $autogrowStatus
+                                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-Object], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way of collecting this data is by capturing it all at the beginning of the `if ($sqlInstance -match "---") {` statement and simply output the PsCustomObjects without trying to convert them.
Something like

```
$sqlinstance = "---"
$query = "---"

$autogrowStatus = if ($sqlInstance -match "---") {
    $dbAutogrowIGP = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $query -ServerInstance $sqlInstance

    if ($dbAutogrowIGP.Growth -gt 100 -and $dbAutogrowIGP.Growth -lt 500) {
        # output the object to be captured in the $autogrowStatus variable
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            'SQL_Instance'  = $dbAutogrowIGP.LogicalName
            'Check'         = "Autogrow"
            'Status'        = "green"
            'Status_reason' = ""
        }
    }

    foreach ($db in $dbAutogrowIGP) {
        if ($db.Growth -lt 100 -or $db.Growth -gt 500 -and $db.Growth -notlike "%") {
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                'SQL_Instance'  = $db.LogicalName
                'Check'         = "Autogrow"
                'Status'        = "red"
                'Status_reason' = "$($db.LogicalName) has autogrowth set to $($db.Growth)."
            }
        }

        if ($db.Growth -like "%") {
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                'SQL_Instance'  = $db.LogicalName
                'Check'         = "Autogrow"
                'Status'        = "yellow"
                'Status_reason' = "$($db.LogicalName) has autogrowth set percentually, it should be an absolute number."
            }
        }
    }
}

return $autogrowStatus
```

The variable `$autogrowStatus` will become an array of PSCustomObjects to handle in the rest of your functions.

Hope this helps

Comment: Amazing, such a simple fix. This works perfectly. Thank you!